# Ajax content refresh with id parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a function which get element value from button and create ajax request. At the beggining 'id' is empty so the JS function below should use 'id=1' but when I click on the button with e.g. value "2" function should load "includes/agallery.php?id=2" to my #agallery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var id = 1;
    $('#agallery').html('Downloading...'); // Show "Downloading..."
    // Do an ajax request
    $.ajax({
      url: "includes/agallery.php?id="+id
    }).done(function(data) { // data what is sent back by the php page
      $('#agallery').html(data); // display data
    });
</script>

<button onClick="" value="2" class="small-btn last"></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a `doAjax` function, which takes an parameter `id` and makes the ajax request
2. Register a click event listener for your button (and remove the one in the html)
3. Make an initial `doAjax` call with `id` 1

This is how it looks like in your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // create a function doAjax
    function doAjax(id) {
        $('#agallery').html('Downloading...'); // Show "Downloading..."
        // Do an ajax request
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/agallery.php?id="+id
        }).done(function(data) { // data what is sent back by the php page
            $('#agallery').html(data); // display data
        });
    }


    $(function() {
        // register a click handler
        $("button.small-btn").click(function() {
            var id = $(this).val();
            doAjax(id);
        });

        // do initial ajax request (with id 1)
        doAjax(1);
    });

</script>
```

In the html remove `onClick=""`, so that the element looks like this:

```
<button value="2" class="small-btn last"></button>
```

Here is a working **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2qRvS/2/)**

Comment: It works only when I do sth like this "<button onClick="doAjax(2)"..." in otherwise nothing happens.

Comment: did you remove the `onClick=""` from the html element?

Comment: I copied all the code agin and still nothing. I don't understand why?

Comment: I've added a demo. Please take a look.

Comment: Sorry :/ Still nothing. I tried different ways with input button, id instead of a class and still nothing. PS. In your demo nothing happens after click the buttons.

Comment: what exactly went wrong? it's strange, because the jsfiddle demo is working (without actually retrieving content, but everything else)

Comment: For me nothing happens in jsfiddle. I was tried in all my browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment the id on before each request.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var id = 0;
    $('#agallery').html('Downloading...'); // Show "Downloading..."
    // Do an ajax request
    id++;
    $.ajax({
      url: "includes/agallery.php?id="+id
    }).done(function(data) { // data what is sent back by the php page
      $('#agallery').html(data); // display data
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you might need this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(".small-btn last").click(function () {
        $('#agallery').html('Downloading...'); // Show "Downloading..."
      // Do an ajax request
    $.ajax({
         url: "includes/agallery.php?id="+$(this).val()
        }).done(function(data) { // data what is sent back by the php page
       $('#agallery').html(data); // display data
        });
});
```